# Rails Model Association Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Hey guys. I have the following models:

- Category
- Event
- Lock
- Item
- Site
- User

`Events` are basically a "log item". In other words, they will store what action was done on what `Item` by what `User` in what `Category`. Naturally, when I thought about this, I figured it "has one User", "has one Category", "has one Item", and so on. However, this would mean that there would be a foreign key for the `Event` in any given `User` row, but this isn't what I want. I want the foreign key in the `Event` row, since the `Event` is just giving information as to what `User`, what `Category`, etc.

So my understanding is that I should instead say that an `Event` "belongs to a user", "belongs to a category", etc. and that they each "have many Events" in return, correct? I'm just making sure, because this doesn't read logically as most other associations. I don't need/want to be able to access an event from the other side (i.e. user.event) because it wouldn't make much sense. So if I do this, would I just add the `belongs_to` call and not the `has_one` on the other side?

Perhaps I designed this incorrectly.

I eventually want to be able to render a 'log page' filled with rows, reach row described a little something like:

```
event.user event.action event.item event.category
```

Comment: Have you looked into acts_as_audited? It doesn't do exactly what you're looking to out of the box. But will with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't need/want to be able to access
>   an event from the other side (i.e.
>   user.event) because it wouldn't make
>   much sense. So if I do this, would I
>   just add the belongs_to call and not
>   the has_one on the other side?

Add them both(`belongs_to` and `has_many`). Sure, `user.event` doesn't make sense, but `user.events` does make sense.

Comment: Hmm this is true. Thanks a lot! So I take it I am correct in my conclusion? event belongs_to user, user has_many events?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here you want to use a has_many & belongs_to association.  In the context of Activerecord, it is the has_many that defines the need for the belongs_to.  "If a model (a) has_many of another model (b) then that associated model (b) belongs_to the first model (a)".

Since a user will have many events associated with it, then an event will belong_to a user.

If on the other hand, a user were to only ever have one event associated with it, then these models would have a "has_one" association.